# Laravel sortBy() includes keys in the output, but sortByDesc doesn't?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fetching a collection with relationship and then I try to sort by a column in one of the relationships. The output for using `sortBy()` is like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
    },
    "0": {
        "id": 2,
    }
}
```

However, when I use `sortByDesc()` it comes out like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
    },
    {  
        "id": 1,
    }
]
```

Is there a reason for this? It doesn't present a problem if I use it inside a Controller or View, however it is used as output in an AJAX call and breaks everything. Is there a way to have consistent output? `sortByDesc()` output works best for me since I don't need keys.

Comment: why not `orderBy()` ?

Comment: @Mohammad `orderBy()` works on DB queries, not collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortBy()` and `sortByDesc()` behave the same way, the difference is your data.

If the sorted result has *consecutive* integer keys (`0, 1, 2`), `json_encode()` will return an array (your second case). Otherwise, `json_encode()` will return an object (your first case).

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct since you give an explanation for my question. Just adding that you can mitigate this behavior by applying the `values()` method on the result. This will give a keyless array regardless of consecutiveness.

Answer (score 3):

you may use something like this

```
$collections->sortBy(function ($collection) {
   return $collection->id;
})->values();
```